# Better way to get multi lines input from console on python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how to handle multi lines input on python 3.

When the input is

```
10
1
6
8
5
4
7
3
2
9
0
```

, and the code is

```
    numbers=[]
    n = int(input()) # Get n numbers
    for i in range(n): # Add n numbers in list
        numbers.append(int(input()))
```

I cannot input the text by copy & paste whole text block, cause python console gave me ValueError.
I have to type line by line using Enter Key on keyboard.

My solution looks like below.

```
    sample_input=input().splitlines()
    n = int(sample_input[0]) # Get n numbers
    data=[]
    for i in range(1, n+1): # Add n numbers in list
        data.append(int(sample_input[i]))
```

But I think this is messy code.
What can be a better way for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```
sample_input=input().splitlines()
sample_input_as_int = [int(value) for value in sample_input]
n, *data = sample_input_as_int

if len(data) != n:
    raise ValueError("wrong number of data provided")
```

Do you really need to ask the user how many numbers they are going to enter?
If they enter only the numbers, you can simplify the code:

```
sample_input=input().splitlines()
data = [int(value) for value in sample_input]
```

Comment: What does *data mean in line 3? Get all values of sample_input_as_int as data list's values except the first one?

Comment: Yes (in the form of the tuple).
Another solution : data = sample_input_as_int[1:]